# Are there any motherboards out there that will let me install 5-6 GPU cards?

Tags: motherboard, gpu

Specifically, I'm looking for GPU cards that take up 2 slots, so spacing is an issue.

Comment: If spacing is an issue, you can always get a PCB printed to "extend" out the PCIe pins to stagger/offset each card (assuming the heatsink isn't blocking the port).

Comment: I forgot to mention... cost effective is a key consideration so whatever I can get out of the box is better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [ASUS P6T6 WS Revolution](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1366/P6T6_WS_Revolution/).

> 6 PCI-E Gen2 x16 IO onboard
>   True @16 3-Way SLI
>   True 16+2 Power Phase Design

[image]

<sup>Er, you say cost-effective being the consideration? Cost tracking is a different ball-game with 6 GPU cards on your system...</sup>
This is not a new board -- here is a [3 year old review](http://hothardware.com/Reviews/Asus-P6T6-WS-Revolution-Core-i7-Motherboard/),

> If you're the type of power user that must have 3-Way SLI or even perhaps just have three graphics cards in your system, you don't currently need three full X16 Gen2 PCI Express-enabled slots to get top performance from a tri-GPU setup.  As we demonstrated in our high-end gaming benchmarks, you definitely would be short-changing yourself with anything less than a X16 and a pair of X8-capable slots but essentially the added cost of NVIDIA's NF200 chip won't buy you any additional gaming performance, at least currently.

<sup>And that is March 2009</sup>

---

More recently, [Asus Rampage III Extreme](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1366/Rampage_III_Extreme/),

> 4 x PCIe 2.0 x16 (dual x16 or x16, x8, x8 or quad x8)

---

Update from your comments:

1. A dual slot card will take up two slots (by definition), but do look at its capabilities ([GeForce GTX 680](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-680))
2. Looking at your plans with the hardware, I'd still suggest going for an [ready-built server-class machine](http://www.eetimes.com/electronics-news/4237703/HP-Proliant-Gen-8-uses-Xeon-E5s-and-Nvidia-Tesla-GPUs-); and before you give up on the price figures, think about the secondary processing you'll need to do on such a hand-built machine (think heat and power [again](http://www.geforce.com/whats-new/articles/boutique-gaming-pc-interview-digital-storm/)).

Comment: But how can I physically place 4 GPU's (or 6) in there? The slots are too close together

Comment: The boards are designed with the intent of dual and tri GPU configurations. The cards will fit in. Your problem will start with cooling and power.

Comment: btw: why not look at ready-built solutions based on say, Nvidia Tesla M2090 devices (HP has some Xeon servers with these installed) -- you will solve the casing problem (pricing is close to $2000 tho).

Comment: Just looking at it, I can tell that a dual slot card will take up the space of 2 slots. That means, I can put in 3 cards at most, no?

Comment: Well. I need the Radeon 7970 since I'm using it for Bitcoin mining, not gameplay. Nvidia typically doesn't mine as well as ATI (https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=16356.0). So I can't pop 6 cards into this motherboard is what you're saying?

Comment: I am saying, managing heat and power requirements of even 3 GPU cards is an arduous task. If you are not a overclock-hacker (usually found within the gaming circles), it would be best to get an off-the-shelf system. You _can_ plug in 6 cards in such a system but there are other complications (I think of the config-space kind) added in. Finally, imo, for a bitcoin reap you would probably find all this bad ROI.

Comment: I currently have a machine with 3 GPU's and it runs no problem. I think that there's a decent ROI with Bitcoin mining if you look at the calculators out there

Answer (score 0):

Last time I looked, I was only able to find motherboards that would support 4 GPUs, but depending on your needs (2D vs 3D), you can drive 12-16 monitors off 3-4 cards.

Comment: I don't need GPU's for monitors. I need them for processing capabilities. Can you tell me which motherboards will support at least 4 GPU's?

Comment: NewEgg will let you search by PCI Express slots. Something like http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157284 might serve your needs.